# AngularJs2 Routing

Tags: angular

My objective is
Route to login page when website loads.
After logged in  show home page by replacing the login-outlet
How could i do it with angularjs2

Here is my code on app.components.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:   '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] 
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent}
    ])
export class AppComponent { }
```

My index.html

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Basic</title>

    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- Router -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

But when i refresh the page, the url is multiplied like
http://localhost:3000/login
http://localhost:3000/login/login

Comment: Did you add a `<base />` tag in your HTML?

Comment: @ Eric Martinez Yes i did. I put my index.html for ref

Comment: i have the same problem before, the change base url like i did in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a local dev, I think you should replace   `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>` with `<base href="/">`

Comment: glad it helps ^_^.  
the base url for index html which is like in the plnkr.co is just for live demo and it would print url like this one: (ex:http://run.plnkr.co/boByZFO8RKLNLKGx/), ie: